# Deploying JavaEE project on Wildfly using ANT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, wildfly, jboss5.x

I have to migrate a JavaEE project from Java 6 + JBoss 5.1 to Java 8 + Wildfly. I'm trying to use Wildfly 20. Do you think an other versionis preferable? I'm totaly new to this topic.
The EAR is deployed with an Ant xml script. I have put the ear in the standalone directory, but I have this error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: AresCommon -- service
> jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.AresCommon

I think there are errors in the Ant script because I didn’t changed anything in the old JBoss script that build the EAR and maybe it doesn’t works with Wildfly and the EJBs are not configured correctly.
Please let me know if you have some examples.

Answer (score 1):

in Wildfly the JNDI-Lookup changes a little bit.

Earlier a jndi-name looks like this:

```
"OrderManagerApp/ProductManagerBean/local"
```

But now it is written like this:

```
"java:app/OrderManagerEJB/ProductManagerBean!services.ejb.ProductManager"
```

You can find detailed information in the [Migration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How%20do%20I%20migrate%20my%20application%20from%20AS5%20or%20AS6%20to%20WildFly.html) at chapter "Update application JNDI namespace names".